# Creating a graphic inside another one using and linking them by lines

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I would like to link a graphic with a another one, both in the same figure, and "connect" the smaller one with the larger one, due to they share X axis, but not Y axis. The problem comes when I use that function, that I really don't know very well how it works.

The function `ax2.set_axes_locator(ip)` calls another one `ip=InsetPosition(ax1,[0.2,0.7,0.5,0.25])`, where `ax1` represents the bigger graphic. The problem is that function automatically generates lines which links the bigger one with the smaller, but I can't redirect them and I want to, because both graphics don't share Y axis.

I hope someone could understand the problem, definitely my english is not the best.

[image]

```py
ax2=plt.axes([0,0,1,1])
ip=InsetPosition(ax1,[0.2,0.7,0.5,0.25])
ax2.set_axes_locator(ip)
mark_inset(ax1,ax2,loc1=3,loc2=4,fc="none",ec='0.5')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `mark_inset` because that will show the marker at the same data coordinates as the view limits of the inset axes.

Instead you can create a rectangle and two connectors that will just be positionned arbitrarily on the axes. (The following code will require matplotlib 3.1 or higher)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from  matplotlib.patches import ConnectionPatch


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1,3,5], [2,4,1])
ax.set_ylim([0, 10])
ax.set_ylabel("Some units")

axins = ax.inset_axes([.2, .7, .4, .25])
axins.plot([100, 200], [5456, 4650])
axins.set_ylabel("Other units")

rect = [2.1, 2.6, 1, 2]
kw = dict(linestyle="--", facecolor="none", edgecolor="k", linewidth=0.8)
ax.add_patch(plt.Rectangle(rect[:2], *rect[2:], **kw))
cp1 = ConnectionPatch((rect[0], rect[1]+rect[3]), (0,0), coordsA="data", axesA=ax,
                      coordsB="axes fraction", axesB=axins, clip_on=False, **kw)
cp2 = ConnectionPatch((rect[0]+rect[2], rect[1]+rect[3]), (1,0), coordsA="data", axesA=ax,
                      coordsB="axes fraction", axesB=axins, clip_on=False, **kw)
ax.add_patch(cp1)
ax.add_patch(cp2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering! Ok, so I need to define the rectangle in which will be shown the second graphic, right? What does exactly does the line where you define "rect"? I'm trying to link it in somehow to your figure but I see no relation. Thanks again.

Comment: The numbers in `rect` are `x0, y0, width, height` of the rectangle in data coordinates.

Comment: Thanks! It will work for me, now I'm dealing with the problem of updating matplotlib since I have an older version

Comment: You don't necessarily need to update, you can keep using the `set_axes_locator`- solution you have; just replace the mark_inset with the parts of this answer.

Comment: I've tried that but it show the next problem:

AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'inset_axes'

Comment: Yes, the `inset_axes` needs matplotlib 3.1, but you can keep using your solution and just take the part of this answer which creates the rectangle and the connecting lines.